# Flutter ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba has terrible Image Quality

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bitmap, rgba

In my project, I need to capture the frame of a flutter animation and save that frame as an image (probably in .png) to Device Storage.

I am using RepaintBoundary to capture the frame, but I can't use the `ui.ImageByteFormat.png` method because it takes a lot of process time to capture the frame as a .png, and since I need to take a lot of frames it will not be a viable solution. Instead, I am using `ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba` which is super fast but when I save it to Storage the image quality is terrible. It hardly looks like it's the same image I captured.

I am using FFMPEG to convert .raw or .bmp format to png and save it to storage.

In both cases, using raw or using BitMap the output image is like this:

[image]

But, the Quality of the Image should be like this
[image]

Now, I need help to either get this raw capture saved with quality by using whatever file format doesn't matter or please share if you have any other viable method to capture frames of a flutter animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, that's not about quality (e.g. a "blur" image is of bad quality). that's because there are some problems on the format - someone must wrongly understand the format when encoding/decoding it.

After looking at your code, it is likely that, your `Bitmap.fromHeadless(300,100,bytes)` has problem. The image is not 300x100! Please correct the size.

Let me explain a bit about the "raw" or "bmp" format. Basically, the format just put pixels one after one onto a big list of bytes. For example, the array looks like: `["red at (0,0)", "green at (0,0)", "blue at (0,0)", "alpha at (0,0)", "red at (0,1)", "green at (0,1)", "blue at (0,1)", "alpha at (0,1)", ...]`. Notice it is row major order. In other words, the order is like "pixel0,0", "pixel0,1", ... "pixel0,k", "pixel1,0", ...

Thus, if you specify the wrong size, then it will be interpreted wrongly - That's why you see that strange-looking image!

About how to get size: After your line of `ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3);`, you can simply do `image.width` and `image.height` to get the correct size.

Please reply if you do not understand something and I am willing to explain ;)

Comment: Thanks, Man you have no Idea how much help you did to me! Best Wishes!

Comment: @RajDhakad Happy to hear that! You can award the bounty to this answer (see last section of [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) for how to do it)

Comment: I have awarded the Bounty on my end even before commenting.

Comment: @RajDhakad That's quite strange... It can still be seen in this page that "the bounty ends in 6 days"

Comment: Well, check now... Thanks for the help again!